# Catch the search value into the variable in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, search, grep

I am trying to search content of file 1 into file 2 and if the content is found then store in found.csv file or store in notfound.csv file

Below is my code,

```
cd /mnt/data/dobiminer/scripts

usage="Usage:sh scriptname.sh 'ToSearchFile' 'MainSearchFile' 'CR' "
Date=`date +%m%d%y%H%M%S`
File=$(<$2)
echo "File Input $2"
echo $File

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
        echo $usage
        exit 1
else
        echo > "$3-Found-$Date.csv"
        echo > "$3-NotFound-$Date.csv"
        for MasterClip in `cat $1`
        do
                echo $MasterClip
                String=$(echo "$File" | grep -x $MasterClip)
                echo $String
                if [ -z $String ];
                then
                        echo "NotFound"
                        echo $MasterClip >> "$3-NotFound-$Date.csv"
                else
                        echo "Found"
                        echo $MasterClip >> "$3-Found-$Date.csv"
                fi
        done
fi
```

My guess is that the below line of code is not working, as whenever I am running the code, the string value is empty only. It is not catching the search value into it.

```
String=$(echo "$File" | grep -x $MasterClip)
echo $String
```

I tried multiple things but not sure where I am going wrong.
THanks for helping me out

Comment: From what I can see, you're searching $MasterClip in the value of $File. At least you should cat instead of echo. That said, why not using "grep -x $MasterClip $File" ?

Comment: What are the contents of the input file `$2`, and what does `echo $MasterClip` print?